# SPHINX Match Phrases only, and SPHINX Automatic Indexing in PHP

Tags: php, linux, indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

I am building a full-text search engine that returns results for phrases.

(a) I am trying to match phrases only using SPH_MATCH_PHRASE in SPHINX using PHP. The problem is that when I search for, e.g. "This is a phrase", it also produces relevant results for "This is a phrase" and "a phrase" and "This is a" and "This is" and "phrase" etc. Is there a way to limit results to ONLY the complete phrase?

What I've tried: I searched S/O and found [How to query Sphinx for an exact matching phrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424780/sphinx-how-do-i-set-sphinx-to-do-exact-string-match) which suggests placing the search query in quotes. I tried it but this returned zero search results when appended to the search terms.

(b) It's my first time using SPHINX, and I have little Linux experience but I managed to get it up and running on a Linux VPS. I started the indexer service but I do not know how to make it re-index all automatically at intervals. Is this a SPHINX configuration or a Linux command?

What I've tried: I searched S/O for (b) above and found this, but for Ruby on Rails [thinking sphinx automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844251/thinking-sphinx-automatic-indexing) so it didn't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *which suggests placing the search query in quotes.*

Yes. Thats for use with Extended Match Mode. `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED`

in php make sure you using $cl->setMatchMode() correctly.

> *I do not know how to make it re-index all automatically at intervals.*

Cron. You setup a crontab job to call the indexer program at what ever interval suits your situation.

Comment: Thanks Barry. But the problem is that we don't want to make the users have to insert the quotes in their query. I tried appending the quotes in the code and then I used SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED but I go no results. I will try again.

As for the Crontab job, I configured the indexer at the Linux prompt so I am not sure how to do the CRON at the Linux prompt... but with a few more hints from you I could be lucky.

Comment: If dont want to do it your self, then use SPH_MATCH_PHRASE, but insert quotes is all sphinx does under the hood when you use SPH_MATCH_PHRASE . Everything is actully evaulated in EXTENDED mode :)

Comment: Hi again Barry. I'll accept your answer because you've been helpful. But really, I have come this far from scratch within 2 days and I still can't figure out the CRON indexing. The links from that google search, I have already looked through them and didn't understand. I'll read more about CRON jobs then. Regards

Comment: This one in particular looks very interesting ... http://wiki.mailspect.com/index.php/Rebuilding_Sphinx_Index and https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction%20cron :)

Comment: Awesome! After reading your links this did it for me. Thanks /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf && killall searchd && /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf

Comment: Uhh, no, thats bad. You are killing searchd, thats really ugly. Just use --rotate instead.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted an answer with --rotate [after testing it myself ] :)

Answer (score 0):

Baryhunter's many links and hints in the accepted answer above proved useful. This did the Indexing part for me, in case anyone needs this later on.

```
/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf && /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd --rotate --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf
```

Comment: Thats wrong too. The --rotate switch goes on indexer. Dont need to call searchd at all `/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf --rotate index_names_here`